# Make base class which operates on a child class

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I know I'm conceptually wrong somewhere here, but how would you arrange this type of situation? I think my confusion would be clear from the code below:

```
  class Base {

    constructor() {
        this._defineProperties( this.properties );
    }

   _defineProperties(properties) {
       properties.forEach((value, key) => {
           Object.defineProperties(this, key, {
             value: value,
             enumerable: true
           })
        });
   }
}


class Child extends Base {

    properties: {
      'title': '',
      'text': ''
    }
}


const obj = new Child();
child.title
child.text
```

Comment: Can you please explain more what you want.

Comment: Hi, imagine I was writing on ORM. So I want users to be able to extend from base model class (or anything), setup model properties by passing an object describing them and base class does all the rest - creates getters and setters based on information stored in an object passed to a child class.. Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: I've found an answer, one can do it via a proxy object